# GET routes not called in express with html

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a very simple app so I didn't think I needed a full-fledged front-end template like angular, and I didn't really want to use Jade

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

Basically I'm returning an html file, and I'm able to call other html files like

```
login.html
signup.html
```

But what confuses me is that my routes are not called. For example I send a GET request to /login but there is no "LOGIN GET" output

//Edit: even with req, res, I can delete this function below and still receive index.html

```
app.get('/login',function(req,res){ 
  console.log("LOGIN GET")
  res.sendFile( path.join( __dirname, 'public', 'login.html' ));    
});
```

How is login.html sent to the client if my route isn't called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you're declaring the catch-all route first:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

app.get('/login',function(req,res){ 
  console.log("LOGIN GET")
  res.sendFile( path.join( __dirname, 'public', 'login.html' ));    
});
```

Because `/login` matches `*`, Express will use the first route to handle requests for `/login` as well. Generally, with Express you need to declare more specific routes first:

```
app.get('/login',function(req,res){ 
  console.log("LOGIN GET")
  res.sendFile( path.join( __dirname, 'public', 'login.html' ));    
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

The reason the other HTML files work is that you probably are using `express.static()` too (but not showing it).

Answer (score 0):

Missing req and res parameters to the route handler. For static file you can also follow https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

```
app.get('/login',function(req, res){ 
  console.log("LOGIN GET")
  res.sendFile( path.join( __dirname, 'public', 'login.html' ));    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Express router.

```
var router = express.Router();
```

And then, you can get

```
router.get("/login",function(req,res){
  console.log("LOGIN GET")
  res.sendFile( path.join( __dirname, 'public', 'login.html' )); 
});
```